# Boto3 DynamoDB Python ConditionalExpression not working

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The goal is only to append the account number if it does not already exist in the list. however it seems to append the account number no matter what so I end up with duplicates. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': id,
            'num': num
        },
        ConditionExpression="NOT contains(#AN, :AN)",
        UpdateExpression="SET #AN = list_append(#AN,:AN)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#AN": "AccountNumber",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":AN": [AccountNumber],
        },
        ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this.
I believe the issue is that list_append is only accepting a List type object.
so ":AN" is a list.
But when it's checking the condition for account number the list object is being checked not the account number itself.
there for it never actually contains the [AccountNumber] but it does contain AccountNumber.